# how can i call a dynamic scheduler to call a method to get tweets several times in a day with rufus-scheduler and Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rufus-scheduler

I need to call tweeter api in a day with fixed time like 1PM, 3PM, 9AM..
I am using twiter gem and rufus-scheduler

Here is my model

```
class Feed < ActiveRecord::Base

  def self.latest
    order('created_at desc').take(500)
  end

  def self.pull_tweets
    $client.search("#ukraine", since_id: maximum(:tweet_id), count: 10).take(10).each do |tweet|

      create!(
        tweet_id: tweet.id,
        content: tweet.text,
        screen_name: tweet.user.screen_name,
        )

     end
 end

end
```

Here is the controller where i am using the scheduler to call pull_tweets

```
class FeedsController < ApplicationController

  def index

    scheduler = Rufus::Scheduler.new
    scheduler.schedule_every('60s') do
      Feed.pull_tweets
    end
   @tweets = Feed.latest
 end
end
```

Its working perfectly but how i can set multiple times like 1AM, 3PM, 9AM for scheduling the task from users input?

Comment: This is bad. Do you realize you're creating a rufus-scheduler instance each time you're requesting /feeds ?

Comment: yes and i think a intializer with a scheduler instance can solve the problem. But can you help me in this regard, please ?

Comment: reading the manual usually helps: https://github.com/jmettraux/rufus-scheduler#so-rails

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simplify your controller to:

```
class FeedsController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @tweets = Feed.latest
  end
end
```

Then make sure you have a config/initializers/scheduler.rb that looks like:

```
require 'rufus-scheduler'

Rufus::Scheduler.singleton.every('60s') { Feed.pull_tweets }
```

So that you have a single scheduler for the whole Ruby process.

To answer your question:

```
require 'rufus-scheduler'

Rufus::Scheduler.singleton.cron('0 1,9,15 * * *') { Feed.pull_tweets }
  # pull tweets at 0100, 0900 and 1500
```

Your code is creating a rufus-scheduler instance each time a browser GETs /feeds, the code here has a single scheduler.

Comment: Would you then please accept my answer? Thanks in advance.

Comment: if i need any help regarding this, i think i can knock you.

Comment: If you don't accept my answer, I don't think I will help you further.

Comment: Thanks a lot dude, now i think i can do the rest of the stuff, though i was thinking before to use cron option, now its possible to put dynamic values by users inside the cron